# Pandas Multiindex wasn't restricted after slicing Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I need to use the first level of a MuliIndex. But after slicing the Dataframe I get the same index.levels[0] as before slicing:

`[] df['2019-04-26 01:00:00':'2020-01-01 22:00:00'].index.levels[0]`

```
[Out] 
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 04:00:00',
               '2019-01-01 07:00:00', '2019-01-01 10:00:00',
               '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '2019-01-01 16:00:00',
               '2019-01-01 19:00:00', '2019-01-01 22:00:00',
               '2019-01-02 01:00:00', '2019-01-02 04:00:00',
               ...
               '2020-02-16 22:00:00', '2020-02-17 01:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 04:00:00', '2020-02-17 07:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 10:00:00', '2020-02-17 13:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 16:00:00', '2020-02-17 19:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 22:00:00', '2020-02-18 01:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=3307, freq=None)
```

The full index sliced correctly, but I want the first level only. Is that a bug or feature of Pandas-1.0.3? How can I get what I want? This Multiindex has already sorted, and I tried to assign another variable for sliced Dataframe, like `df1 = df['2019-04-26 01:00:00':'2020-01-01 22:00:00']` and I got the same `df1.index.levels[0]`

Added:
Sorted MultiIndex is:

```
            ('2019-01-01 01:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2019-01-01 04:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2019-01-01 04:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2019-01-01 07:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2019-01-01 07:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2019-01-01 10:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2019-01-01 10:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2019-01-01 13:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2019-01-01 13:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ...
            ('2020-02-16 22:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 01:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 04:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 07:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 10:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 13:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 16:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 19:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-17 22:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-02-18 01:00:00',    'Досанг')],
           names=['Дата', 'Location'], length=13185)
```

Then I wanted to drop dates what have not the full list of locations. I calculated the boundaries to restrict by and sliced the dataframe:
`date_frame=(Timestamp('2019-04-26 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-01 22:00:00'))`
so, for `df[date_range[0]:date_range[1]].index`
I got

```
            ('2019-04-26 01:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2019-04-26 01:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2019-04-26 01:00:00',  'Харабали'),
            ('2019-04-26 01:00:00', 'Черный Яр'),
            ('2019-04-26 04:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2019-04-26 04:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2019-04-26 04:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2019-04-26 04:00:00',  'Харабали'),
            ('2019-04-26 04:00:00', 'Черный Яр'),
            ...
            ('2020-01-01 19:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2020-01-01 19:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-01-01 19:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2020-01-01 19:00:00',  'Харабали'),
            ('2020-01-01 19:00:00', 'Черный Яр'),
            ('2020-01-01 22:00:00', 'Астрахань'),
            ('2020-01-01 22:00:00',    'Досанг'),
            ('2020-01-01 22:00:00',   'Зеленга'),
            ('2020-01-01 22:00:00',  'Харабали'),
            ('2020-01-01 22:00:00', 'Черный Яр')],
           names=['Дата', 'Location'], length=10040)
```

but for `df[date_range[0]:date_range[1]].index.levels[0]` I'm always got

```
               '2019-01-01 07:00:00', '2019-01-01 10:00:00',
               '2019-01-01 13:00:00', '2019-01-01 16:00:00',
               '2019-01-01 19:00:00', '2019-01-01 22:00:00',
               '2019-01-02 01:00:00', '2019-01-02 04:00:00',
               ...
               '2020-02-16 22:00:00', '2020-02-17 01:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 04:00:00', '2020-02-17 07:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 10:00:00', '2020-02-17 13:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 16:00:00', '2020-02-17 19:00:00',
               '2020-02-17 22:00:00', '2020-02-18 01:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Дата', length=3307, freq=None)
```

Comment: u mind posting the source multiIndex, as well as ur expected output.

Comment: sammywemmy, I added that to post

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolve like:

`new_idx = df['2019-04-26 01:00:00':'2020-01-01 22:00:00'].reset_index(1).index`

But it is not quite elegant, I think